# Pointer to type with undefined access right in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers

C++ has this 3 types o char:

- `signed char`   - signed character
- `unsigned char` - unsigned character
- `char`          - character which have not defined if its signed or unsigned

"Analogically", have C++ also 3 pointer types? :

- `const int*` - pointer to constant `int`
- `int*`       - pointer to mutable  `int`
- `???`        - pointer to `int` which have not defined if its const or mutable

What use instead of `???` in C++ ?

Comment: There's no analogy. But there is a `volatile` and a `mutable` qualifier. Also note that `char` is only undefined in as much as an implementation can make it signed or unsigned. But it is well defined within an implementation.

Comment: "access" in C++ refers to `public/protected/private`, i.e. class members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're mistaken that `const int*` is necessarily a pointer to a `const int`. Example:

```
int a; // Not const;
int const* p = &a; // Valid
```

Therefore, `int const volatile*` is the answer. It can point to any cv-qualified `int`.

Answer (score 0):

C++ does not support, "exact type of this type to be defined later in the program"; some types are best - "implementation is system dependent".

So there is no equivalent for this in C++. A pointer, any pointer, is either const or non const.

A char is NOT "character which have not defined if its signed or unsigned"; c++ standard - "type for character representation which can be most efficiently processed on the target system (has the same representation and alignment as either signed char or unsigned char, but is always a distinct type).". So char is always one of the types NOT undefined.

Comment: *"So char is always one of the types"* - contradicts the section of the Standard you'd just finished quoting: it has the same representation and alignment, but is *not the same type*.  This matters for e.g. template instantiations and specialisation (e.g. see http://ideone.com/5RHTUp)